# My DataGrip run/debug configuration wrong and can`t run SQL console script

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I　am learning mySQL and practice basic syntax using DataGrip. Unkownly, I can`t run my console script.

For example,I enter `SELECT * FROM table` in the console window,and click the green button 'run', But it can`t run as ususal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you go to the context menu and press 'Run console_1' or used the green arrow on the upper toolbar. This actually created a run configuration for the whole script. And it is noе what you needed. To run just a single query:

1. Use the green arrow button on the console toolbar.
   [image: List item]
2. Or the shortcut: Cmd+Enter
3. Or in the context menu choose `Execute`

[image]